# Stochastic Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, absolute-convergence

I need help figuring out if a series of "apparently random" digits are the result of the same (possibly non-polynomial) function, ergo, not-random but deterministic.

The highest level math I know is calculus and I never had to take probability. From wikipedia and several sources it appears "convergence" is what I'm looking for. However, I was rather confused by the articles given a lack of background in probability.

For example, imagine three sets of integers:

- S_1: 13,101,413
- S_2: 15,141,411
- S_3: 86,753,009

Are they the result of a function F? If so, how would I determine the function that spat those integers out as output?

Please help me out with this

Comment: Given any finite series of numbers, there exists a polynomial p such that p(1), p(2), p(3), ... generates those series of numbers. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: *sounds* about right

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837902/prove-there-exists-a-unique-n-th-degree-polynomial-that-passes-through-n1-p

Comment: thanks that appears to be it