# $P(x)=P(-x)$ holds for all values of $x$ ,two conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was doing a question on polynomials , where it was found that 
$P(x)=P(-x)$ in the interval $[-\sqrt2,\sqrt 2 ]$
It was then concluded that $P(x)=P(-x)$ holds for all values of $x$ ,"since it is a polynomial".
Can someone help me understand why it could be  generalized ?

Edit - $P(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients .

Comment: Your title is misleading: it holds  for all $x$ because of *two* things as the answers make clear: 1) $P(x)$ is a polynomial and 2) it is equal to some other polynomial *at an infinite number of points* - in that case, the two polynomials *have* to be equal at all points.

Comment: Thanks ,I will change it

Answer (score 7):

Let $Q(x)=P(x)-P(-x)$, then $Q(x)$ is a real polynomial since $P(x)$ is (make sure you can show this!). By the assumption, $Q$ has infinitely many roots. But *the only real polynomial with infinitely many roots is the zero polynomial.* Hence $Q(x)=0$ for all real $x$, so $P(x)=P(-x)$ for all real $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If polynomial $f(x)$ has degree less than $n$, then $n+1$ number of points on the polynomial determines the polynomial.

Since $P(x) - P(-x)$ is a polynomial, and there are infinite number of $t \in [-\sqrt 2, \sqrt2]$ satisfying $P(t) - P(-t) = 0$, we have $P(x) - P(-x) \equiv 0 $ as function.

Comment: "If polynomial f(x) has degree less than n, then n+1 number of points on the polynomial determines the polynomial."-Why is this true?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837902/prove-there-exists-a-unique-n-th-degree-polynomial-that-passes-through-n1-p

Comment: @Grace500 Let $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$ and $(x_0, y_0), \cdots, (x_n, y_n)$ be the points of the polynomial, i.e. $f(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i \in \{0, \cdots, n\}$. Then we have the linear system of $a_0, \cdots, a_n$. $n+1$ number of variables, $n+1$ number of equations. And the system is linearly independent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix